# How does mark sweep algorithm for garbage collection work in java and differ in JVMs?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I had certain issues while understanding the Internal working of garbage collection. How does internal garbage collection work in java using mark sweep algorithm?

Basically what i wanted to understand are the two points.

```
1. How Garbage Collection differs in the three big JVMs?

2. Performance Tuning in JVMs when performing Garbage Collection?
```

PS - I did have a good workout on Google, it did show with a lot of textual stuff which I found difficult to understand. But I am looking for a more animated and good explanation.

Comment: This is very broad. Did you have a specific question about this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23883104/concurrent-mark-and-sweep-algorithm-details

Comment: GC simply is a very complex topic and takes a lot of effort to understand in detail.

Comment: Moderators of stackoverflow..I have edited my question..and given the exact question...Please donr mark it as duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Garbage collection implementations are complicated, change relatively often, and sometimes differ even within the same release. The following answer gives a reading list which should introduce you to the concepts, after which you would be able to understand the answers to your question:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1319064/138304